# What is the common way to get images from urls in android application

Tags: android, image, httpurlconnection

I see a lot of android applications just look like html pages, containing many images here and there. But I don't know usually how these applications get their images to render. Do they get images through url. I found some posts on the internet suggested to use AsyncTask to download image through a HttpURLConnection . But I think AsyncTask is a little bit too complicated which involves too much code. Can anyone recommend me a simple,brief and may be also standard approach to get images to render in android applications?Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: you can use glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide as it will take care of all the memory management for you and because it's a quite light weight library.

Comment: Thank you. Ajinkya S also recommended it. I am going to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an image loading library, like Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide), Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) or Fresco (https://github.com/facebook/fresco) among others.

Comment: Thank you. These libs are exactly what I am looking for. They all look great.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest using glide as it is lightweight and easy to use.

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

And also has its own many features.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. Its really hard to choose one out of them because they all offer similar functions and look great. The lightweight and easy to use matter a lot to me but the other two libs also get many high ratings. I think I need some extra time to make more comparison.

Comment: There is no memory leakage issue in glide

Comment: Thank you. Finally I decide to join glide as long as it works for my need.